# Proabability in Scrabble expected number does it take to draw a blank,(yes replacement)

Tags: statistics

In the game of Scrabble, players begin by drawing 7 tiles from a bag containing 100 tiles, 2 of which are blank. A player cheats by looking at the first tile he draws, and if it is not blank, he replaces the tile and draws again, repeating this process until he draws a blank tile. What is the expected number of draws this player must make until he draws a blank tile?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the number of draws the player has to make to draw a blank. The probability that any given draw is a success is $\frac{1}{50}$ and we continue until we succeed so $X$ is geometrically distributed with parameter $\frac{1}{50}$.

The expected value of a geometrically distributed random variable with probability $p$ is $\frac{1}{p}$, so in your case, the expected number of draws the player must make is $50$.